# Wordpress: How to select a menu for mobile Woocommerce pages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, menu

I'm trying to put a different menu on the Woocommerce pages of my Wordpress site. An extra condition is that this menu only has to be displayed if the site is visited by an mobile device. I've tried the following code in my header.php file, but it didn't work out. Anyone who can help me?

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() && ($pagename == 'page-name') ) {
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'mobile-menu' ) );
}
```

Comment: first check wp_is_mobile() is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register the menu then you need to assign menu items to it.

you can verify the following link

[mobile menu](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/4-easy-steps-to-adding-a-mobile-menu-on-your-wordpress-website/)

Comment: I already created a special menu under Appearance > Menu. The theme (Salient) supports mobile menu's. Now the normal menu appears on mobile devices as well.